# mutli-domain cookies in express redirecting localhost to mydomain.com

Tags: session, cookies, express, cross-domain

I've got an app where I'm trying to allow the user to create their own subdomains. 
In order to get this working locally while developing and testing, I've had to setup a few available subdomains in my hostfile.

For login, I'm using oauth, and google is the first provider I'm working with.

When a user logs in from `mydomain.com` google forces the redirect auth to `localhost`. I've written a bit of middleware that checks if the `req.get('host')` is `localhost`, it redirects to `mydomain.com`.

This seems to work fine, except that it appears that express doesn't match the sessions from the one returned by `localhost` when the redirect goes to `mydomain.com`.

As this is only for dev and testing, is there a way to allow express to share all the session info across domains, or add a whitelist?

The stuff I've found on SO has pointed me to have my redirect middleware as

```
module.exports = function(baseUrl){
    var base = baseUrl.split(':');
    base = base[1].replace('//','');
    return function(req, res, next) {

        console.log('in redirect');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', base);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
        if(req.hostname.indexOf('localhost') > -1) {
            var redirect = req.get('host').replace('localhost', base);
            console.log('redirect is', redirect, req.path);
            return res.redirect(redirect + '/');
        }
        next();
    }
}
```

but then in my post login route, I need to check if the requested url is localhost, and if so, then I need to replace it. For some reason, the middleware isn't being called in this route. It is called when I initially

```
 function createUrl(req, subdomain){
    var domain = req.get('host') === 'localhost:3000' ? 'mydomain.com:3000' : req.get('host');
    var url = req.protocol + '://' + subdomain + '.' + domain;
    return url + '/team'
}

function redirectToSubdomain(req, res){
    var url = createUrl(req, "me");
    console.log('new url is ', url);
    res.redirect(url)
}
router.get('/', auth.isAuthenticated(), function(req, res) {
    var team = Team.getSubdomain(req);
    if(team.error) return redirectToSubdomain(req, res);
    return res.render('team', req.data);
});
```

I've tried setting my cookie to accept all domains as

```
app.use(passport.session({cookie: { secure: true, domain: '*'}}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using `dev.localhost` as the main url to the development site, than `subdomain.dev.localhost` for subdomains, and in my cookie set `domain: '.dev.localhost'`. Worked a treat.